# Naudio or FMOD libraries in Silverlight applications

Tags: silverlight, naudio, fmod

I have to grab audio from a microphone and write it to stream 'on fly'. The destination machine will read this data and play it. It's all will be Silverlight applications. So can i use Naudio library or FMOD for my purpose?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

No, those libraries will not be available.

Silverlight 4 will support microphone access but has only had a beta release at this time.

Comment: I'm hoping to make some parts of NAudio available for Silverlight to allow some DSP etc, but anything involving P/Invoke will never be available. Wait for Silverlight 4 as Jeff said.